# Starting activity in Android - Eclipse always shows an error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've got this code in my app that after five seconds open another activity.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    startActivity(R.layout.activity_game);
  }
},5000);
```

But Eclipse doesn't like this...:

View error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh8Id.png

But when I choose one of those methods, Eclipse wants the startActivity() again!

What can I do?

Comment: See [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
```

[Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 3):

To start activity use this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

If you are using `Fragment` try `getActivity();` instead of `FirstActivity.this`,   or if you in normal activity try `getApplicationContext();` instead of `FirstActivity.this` or just use `this`.

Comment: @Yvette He didn't provide code and he seems to be beginner, so i just want from him to give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityGame.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 5000);
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

if is this `Fragment` then use

```
getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),YOURACTIVITY.class));
```

and if is this `activity` then

```
startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity.this,YOURACTIVITY.class));
```